# Objective c - Get non-english characters from sqlite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, character, non-english

I really have searched for the answer, but I didn't find my answer :(

The problem is non-english characters (French and Greek), with just english characters it works fine.

I get stuff out a sqlite database, wich goes flawlessly with English characters, but not with French or Greek ones.

At this point it goes wrong:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
```

This return false, so the program doesn't go on.

I have read things about UTF-8 and UTF-16.
It would be sqlite3_open for UTF-8, and sqlite3_open16 for UTF-16.
When I use `sqlite3_open16`, it doesn't open at all.

I have to open databases with French characters and one with Greek.
Anyone knows what to do?

This is the code where I open the database:

```
startLanguage = the language where I start with, this is also the database name.
databasePath = the path to the database file. e.g.: /Users/joeranbosma/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/80C89C95-418D-487F-B697-6BEA4B0DAA66/Documents/frans.sql

-(void) readWordsFromDatabase {
    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;

    // Init the words Array
    words = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        NSString *mySQLstatement = [@"select * from " stringByAppendingString:startLanguage];
        const char *sqlStatement = [mySQLstatement UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                // Read the data from the result row
                NSString *woordA = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSString *woordB = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

                // Create a new word object with the data from the database
                Word *word = [[Word alloc] initWithWordA:woordA wordB:woordB];

                // Word *words = [[Word alloc] initWithWordName:aName description:aDescription url:aImageUrl];

                // Add the word object to the words Array
                [words addObject:word];

                [word release];
            }
        }

        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

}
```

**Edit 1**
I have found a solution!
If you put everything into one file, and make multiple tables it works.

I would love to know why this is, so if anybody knows I would appreciate that